# saving cloned buffers in workspaces/desktops/perspectives etc

Tags: org-mode, desktop

i would like to be able to save a window (in emacs terms) layout with cloned buffers. i don't need it to save a series of buffers, i just need to be able to load a complex window layout when i work on a particular file. i want to show narrowed headings in different windows.

- i know i can save layouts to a register and this works, but only as long as the emacs daemon is going. i wd prefer a solution that didn't rely on the emacs daemon. the file is a long term project.
- i know i can save my register by saving the desktop, but this doesn't work: the register is saved but it doesn't open my cloned buffers correctly, it gives ```Error (frameset): font 'tty' is not defined and doesn't open them. (i tried both frame and window registers)
- i tried `persp-mode`. it saves the windows correctly, and the buffers in them even have the names of clones, but they're completely empty when i load. (& can't unnarrow to anything.) this model (saving to a user defined file), seems like the right approach tho.
- i tried `persistence-mode`. it restored no windows, and no cloned buffers, only frames.
- `workspaces2` is basically unmaintained.

perhaps someone has experience with fulfilling this kind of need.